# Regex for any matches from a list of words not preceded by @

Tags: regex, hex, sublimetext2, keyword, keyword-argument

I inherited a front-end web project with a few dozen grossly disorganized Less pages. I need to track down stray colors and unify with a brand standard. My understanding of regex is fairly limited, but if I understand correctly, one or more might make my life a lot easier.

I'm using the "Find in Files..." > Regular expression feature in Sublime Text 2.

My strategy is to match all HEX codes with:
**#[0-9a-fA-F]+\b**
This appears to be working for me, but I'm wondering if there are any inadequacies?

And next for all keyword colors I'm trying:
**\b(white|black|gray|red|etc|)\b**
However, this returns my variables as well (i.e. @gray, @red, etc).

I need to match any words from a given list only if not preceded by @ symbol.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Um, `gr[ea]y`  there. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\b(?<!@)(white|black|gray|red|etc)\b
```

You can make you `negative lookbehind` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/5